# Django / Rest Framework, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute id

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django / Rest Framework, i would like to get the inserted record id

i did :

```
formSerializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
        if formSerializer.is_valid():
            newContact = formSerializer.save()
            print(newContact.id)
```

but i'm getting an error :

```
print(newContact.id)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `many=True` which will create multiple contacts.

To print all new contact ids.

```
newContact = formSerializer.save()
for contact in newContact:
     print(contact.id)
```